# Cannot log into new mysql server for setup CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, linux, lamp, centos7

I am having trouble understanding why I cannot log into a new mqsql server install in a new install of Centos 7. Here is what I've done:

Install CentOS 7 Minimal

```
yum update
yum install apache
yum install mysql
setenforce 0
mysql_secure_installation
```

All of this runs fine except the last one. I get:
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

```
Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've been through resetting the sql root p/w and other security things, but with a fresh install should I really have to?

I've never had so many issues with a fresh install of linux before :( What am I missing?

Comment: Are you entering the linux root or the mysql root password? you need to enter mysql root password. I'm guessing you are login-in from a shell on your host. I don't recall all what i had to do to mkae it work on my el7 but itt was a pain.  There also some subtilities bewteen mariaDB and Mysql so be sure to use the good stuff. Wish i could help more but it was months ago.

Comment: This is a completely new installation of both linux and mysql so I have set no password as the system did not exist before. I have been trying the root user p/w or even creating another user in the system. I cannot get mysql to allow me to create any other users to try and use.

Comment: Have you tried logging in using `sudo mysql`?

Comment: or log in with skip--grant--table like when you reset the root password see this link i followed : :https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password

Comment: Yes, I have used both sudo mysql (using another user) and --skip-grant-table. It this point I'm tired of fighting a new and empty mysql. I am going to rebuild the VM entirely. Does anyone know of a good tutorial to follow for lamp on Centos7? Clearly I seem to be missing something in this process.

Answer (score 0):

When You get this point of installation of MySQL server on centOS7 you must just enter the button enter and then you will get a question for your new password and re-type new password. This is because default password for MySQL is empty.